# Is there a way to use .flac files in Audiosurf?

Tags: audiosurf

A while ago, I played  the game [Audiosurf](http://audio-surf.com/) on a friends computer and I remember it to be good fun. The problem is, if I remember correctly, the game only supports the usage of .mp3 files (and maybe .wav).

Since I have ripped all my CDs to .flac files and do not want to make .mp3 copies of my collection, I would like to know, is there a way to use .flac files in Audiosurf?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is. Audiosurf can already play FLAC files out of the box. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5G7l.jpg))

This isn't listed on its [Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/12900/), but I own it, and FLAC files are definitely supported. Seems kind of silly not to advertise this as a selling point, but there you go.

For future reference, this is the list of file extensions the current file browser accepts:

> mp3, wma, m4a, m3u, ogg, **flac**, wav

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will accept it in a few minutes when I am allowed to do so... I guess the game will be worth its money then :)